# Kafka Seek To Beginning with Python API?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

With the Kafka Java API, I can use a rebalance listener that seeks to the beginning of the topic like this (code is Scala, Kafka API is Java):

```
class SeekToBeginningRebalanceListener[K, V](val consumer: KafkaConsumer[K, V]) extends ConsumerRebalanceListener {
  override def onPartitionsAssigned(partitions: util.Collection[TopicPartition]): Unit = {
    for (tp <- partitions.asScala) {
      consumer.seekToBeginning(util.Arrays.asList(tp))
    }
  }

  override def onPartitionsRevoked(partitions: util.Collection[TopicPartition]): Unit = { }
}
```

And I would use that when subscribing to a topic like this:

```
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(java.util.Arrays.asList(topicName), new SeekToBeginningRebalanceListener(kafkaConsumer))
```

How can I do that with the confluent-kafka python api?

I can write a similar partition assignment callback function that gets invoked:

```
def on_assign_callback(consumer, topic_partitions):
    for topic_partition in topic_partitions:
        print("assigned to partition. topic={}. partition={}. offset={}. error={}".format(
            topic_partition.topic, topic_partition.partition, topic_partition.offset, topic_partition.error))

        # This runs but has no effect.
        topic_partition.offset = 0
```

But I can't find any API to do a seek. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you going to use the method 'only ' for rebalancing or was that just to outline the example? You can use the `'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'}` on the config, for the offset to go to the beginning.

Comment: The purpose is to seek to the beginning of the topic. The partition assignment callback is just the easiest place to do that.

Comment: "we're currently missing a seek method"  This might answer your query https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/11#issuecomment-230047766

Comment: The `auto.offset.reset` configuration option is only when there are no committed offsets. In the referenced github thread ewencp suggests simply deleting the consumer group with kafka-consumer-groups.sh and starting fresh. That doesn't work either when using "new consumers". Maybe I should start a new thread on that?

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/11

this works for me :

```
def on_assign (c, ps):
    for p in ps:
        p.offset=-2
    c.assign(ps)

c.subscribe(['test'], on_assign=on_assign)
```

`seekToBeginning` function for Confluent Kafka Python API is not currently implemented.